# Loop through worksheets while exporting range as image

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA code that works to export a range of cells into a jpeg into a specified folder. I would like to have it loop through all worksheets in one workbook.

I need help looping this code through all open workbooks. I believe I will need to:
Dim WS As Worksheet, then set up an If statement, insert the below code, end the if statement, then at the end put a Next WS for it to actually loop through. My problem is, is that I keep getting a 91 error when I try to combine my if statement, For Each WS In ThisWorkbook.Sheets If Not WS.Name = "Sheet2" Then, with my code below.

The following code works in one worksheet at a time.

```
Sub ExportAsImage()
Dim objPic As Shape
Dim objChart As Chart
Dim i As Integer
Dim intCount As Integer
'copy the range as an image
Call ActiveSheet.Range("A1:F2").CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)
'remove all previous shapes in the ActiveSheet
intCount = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
For i = 1 To intCount
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Delete
Next i
'create an empty chart in the ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart
'select the shape in the ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Width = Range("A1:F2").Width
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Height = Range("A1:F2").Height
Set objChart = ActiveChart
'clear the chart
objChart.ChartArea.ClearContents
'paste the range into the chart
objChart.Paste
'save the chart as a JPEG
objChart.Export ("C:\Users\------\Desktop\Test\" & Range("B2").Value &     ".jpg")
'remove all shapes in the ActiveSheet
intCount = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count
For i = 1 To intCount
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Item(1).Delete
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include all your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your module:

```
Sub MAIN()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    For Each sh In Sheets
        sh.Activate
        Call ExportAsImage
    Next sh
End Sub
```

and run it. *(there is no need to modify your code)*